# Is refcursor working in postgresql 13.2 version?

Tags: postgresql-13

IN my postgresql 13.2 version database, the "refcursor" is not working.
when am i storing the select query output to refcursor variable, it is throwing below error.

```
create function testing(val character varying)
return t_cur
language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
v_return t_cur;
begin
open v_return.v_output for select * from tbl_master where id = val;
return v_return;
end;
$function$
```

In this stored procedure **"t_cur" is user defined type**. and **v_output is refcursor variable**.

**Error:**

```
Error: cursor variable must be a simple variable
LINE 67: open V_RETURN.V_OUTPUT for select * from...
```

This same stored procedure is working properly in postgresql version 9.6

So please explain what is replacement of refcursor in postgresql 13.2 verson.
or what is the solution for this?

Comment: Why use a refcursor at all? You can define the function as `returns table (...)` or even `returns setof tbl_master`  and return the result directly.

Comment: i am executing this sp through PHP program. and getting the tbl_master table output through that cursor veriable.